# PrimeFaces Push Faces Message Notify not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push-notification, jsf-2.2

I have problem with the Push Technology, the project is to:

- Primefaces 3.5
- WebLogic 12c
- Atmosphere Runtime 2.2

The configuration is:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

The View:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class FrmNotificacion  implements Serializable 
...
  public void send() {
    ...
       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Usuario: "+getUser(), getMensajeDetalle());
       PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
       pushContext.push("/notificacion",  msg);
       System.out.println("......");
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

The XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <title>Enivar Notificación</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="frmPrincipal" >
            <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />
            <p:panel header="Notificación" >
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="ui-widget-header,,ui-widget-header,,ui-widget-header,," >
                    <p:outputLabel  id="lblNombre"  value="Ingrese Usuario a Notificar:" />
                    <p:inputText id="txtNombre" value="#{frmNotificacion.user}" />
                    <p:outputLabel id="lblMensaje" value="Ingresar Mensaje Notificación" />
                    <p:inputTextarea id="txtMensaje" autoResize="true" value="#{frmNotificacion.mensajeDetalle}"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton id="btnNotifica"
                                 value="Notifica"
                                 update="message"
                                 actionListener="#{frmNotificacion.send()}"
                                 icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

        <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notificacion"  />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(msg) {
                msg.severity = 'info';
                grow.show([msg]);
            }
        </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

But the action notify push Faces Message not working

Maybe the configuration is wrong

It also shows me this console:

```
INFO: Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
03-feb-2015 9:09:50 org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor action
ADVERTENCIA: Websocket protocol not supported
03-feb-2015 9:09:50 org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor action
GRAVE: Invalid request state. AsyncContext#startAsync not supported. Make sure async-supported is set to true in web.xml   
03-feb-2015 9:09:52 org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework$4 run
INFO: Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.2.6
```

Comment: You have an unsupported combination of PrimeFaces and Atmosphere afaik

Comment: why ¿? I have Atmosphere Runtime 2.2

Comment: Because the PF 3.5 docs (page 467, 5.1 Setup (of PF Piush) state a dependency on Atmosphere 1.0.0.RC1.  2.2 is waaaaay newer

Comment: No, why with  Atmosphere 1.0.0.RC1. , show message that one class no exist, for that use Atmosphere Runtime 2.2

Comment: **what** class? It's weird that PF 3.5 would give you an error about a class that it requires if that is in 2.2 and the docs state that 1.0.0.RC1 is required.

Comment: maybe the version 1.0.0 its deprecated

Comment: The class is: <03-feb-2015 12H14' GMT-05:00> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1422983664255" for task "23". Error is: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.CometProcessor"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.CometProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Change JavaScript:

Last:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(msg) {
            msg.severity = 'info';
            grow.show([msg]);
        }
    </script>
```

For This:

```
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function handleMessage(data) {
           alert("Hola");
        }
    </script>
```

as I do that I work at the FacesMessage ¿?

Comment: So with this partially works? Then your errors in the serverlog were totally unrelated? Question then is where is 'grow' defined? Sure there was no javascript error?